# How to determine boot time in SysV?

Tags: boot, sysvinit, sysv

In systemd-based distros there is a tool run via systemd-analyze which allows the user to determine boot time [kernel and userspace, the time it took for the system to boot up]. Is there a similar command which can be run for SysV?

Comment: Do you by "boot time" mean the time when the system booted, or the time it took for the system to boot?

Comment: @Kusalananda, I should have clarified, the time it took for the system to boot up, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

`bootchart2` is your friend with `sysv`.